# Cycle double cover conjecture for complete graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, topological-graph-theory

The cycle double cover conjecture states that for every bridgeless finite $G$ there is a collection of cycles $\mathcal{C}$ in $G$ such that every edges on $G$ occurs in precisely two of the cycles in $\mathcal{C}$.  Is the cycle double cover conjecture known for complete graphs?

I would actually be interested in knowing about stronger results pertaining to the various stronger versions of the double cover conjecture - for example does every complete graph admit a strong embedding into some orientable surface (i.e. every face is a cycle in the graph)?  Can we take it to be 5-face colorable?

I am also interested in the same question for complete bipartite graphs.  References would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete graph with an *odd* number of vertices has a *single* cycle cover: Arrange the vertices in a regular polygon and consider each possible length of diagonals separately. Now just take each of those cycles twice.

If you have an *even* number of vertices, then set one of them aside and split the rest of the graph into cycles as above. Then take *one* of the resulting outer cycles and disassemble it into single edges; let each of those edges make a triangle with the vertex you set aside. This again gives a cycle double cover.